# Make specific folders writeable in laravel coaster cms in google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform

Currently I am using google app engine with laravel custom cms coaster cms. How can I make the following folders writable?

[image: Error on Google App engine]

Tried all normal commands, `chmod` given permission check the above image

[image: permission for the folders]

Comment: You might want to check this thread where a similar question was fielded by GCP Support - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/y9wMdeqyJsA/jiwYb_kYBAAJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While App Engine runs on VM's, this does not mean that you should rely on changing their permissions. Remember that App Engine is a managed VM, this means that even if you make the folders writable on an instance, if App Engine scales up or has to destroy the instance you modified,  you would need to make the changes on the new instances (which you shouldn't be doing).

I would recommend you to use Compute Engine with a managed instance group in order to solve this issue as this would be more practical than to mingle with every instance that spawns for you app.

Comment: The AppEngine Standard instances run in a container on Borg.  The AppEngine Flexible instances are based on Compute Engine VMs.  Your answer is still correct in both cases, though.

Comment: @rsalinas your answer is correct for future enhancement using ci/cd pipeline but how to make changes to the current vm file system

Answer (score 3):

You can put the commands you need to make Coaster CMS folders writable, in a [dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#docker) for your App Engine Flex VMs. That way when the VM is launched, it's properly configured.

If that doesn't work, then you can use [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to setup/configure all your GCE VMs at startup.

Comment: You provided "startup scripts" for `google cloud compute engine` not for `google appengine`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I made clarifications now. It's two separate solutions. Dockerfile for GAE Flex or if you need more use startup scripts for your GCE VMs.

Answer (score 0):

If the process that the web server runs on is `saurabh2836`, then you need to add the write permission for the directories listed:

`chmod -R u+x public/coaster public/themes public/uploads`