# uploading images work perfect on the localhost, won't work on the live site(google app engine and laravel)

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine

my project is working perfectly on the local host and as soon as i deploy it to the live server using the command `gcloud app deploy`. The deploy maybe runs successful and as soon as i try uploading an image image on the live site it throw error 500 and when i check my logs i got the following errors:

```
ErrorException: mkdir(): Permission denied
at mkdir (/app/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Service/AddServiceController.php:74)
at App\Http\Controllers\admin\Service\AddServiceController->store (/app/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Service/AddServiceController.php:74)
at call_user_func_array ([internal function])
at Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54)
at Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45)
at Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:225)
at Illuminate\Routing\Route->run (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:182)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:681)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
at Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authorize.php:45)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity->handle (/app/app/Http/Middleware/LastUserActivity.php:26)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:76)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:56)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:683)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:658)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:624)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:613)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:165)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:63)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle (/app/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php:36)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle (/app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:140)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:109)
at {main} (/app/public/index.php:55)
```

second error massage:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path (/app/public/uploads/services/1593957045.jpeg)
at App\Http\Controllers\admin\Service\AddServiceController->store (/app/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php:150)
at call_user_func_array ([internal function])
at Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54)
at Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45)
at Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:225)
at Illuminate\Routing\Route->run (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:182)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:681)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
at Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authorize.php:45)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity->handle (/app/app/Http/Middleware/LastUserActivity.php:26)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:76)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:56)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:683)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:658)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:624)
at Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:613)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:165)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:63)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle (/app/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php:36)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle (/app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:167)
at Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:140)
at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle (/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:109)
at {main} (/app/public/index.php:55)
```

My Controller:

```
        $service = new Add_Service;
        // Handle the user upload of avatar
        if($request->hasFile('service')){
            $image = $request->file('service');
            $filename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $destinationPath = 'uploads/services/';
            if (!file_exists(storage_path($destinationPath))) {
                mkdir(storage_path($destinationPath), 755, true);
            }

            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(1000, 667, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.$filename);

            $service->image = $filename;
            $service->service_name = ucfirst(request('service_name'));
            $service->desc = ucfirst(request('service_desc'));
            $service->save();
         }
```

my composer:

```
       "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
```

please assist. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This is a permission issue on your `/app/public/uploads` directory. Just change the permission

Comment: how do i change them

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permissions of your `/app/public/uploads` directory, as @STA mentioned in the comments, will fix the issue and you can do it by using this command in Cloud Shell:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w <directory>
```

However, this will likely not be a permanent fix nor a best practice on the use of App Engine, because of the structure that App Engine runs on top of.

As you can see in this [Community Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155743/12857703):

> App Engine is a managed VM, this means that even if you make the folders writable on an instance, if App Engine scales up or has to destroy the instance you modified, you would need to make the changes on the new instances.

So, if you are using this folder to store temp files, I would recommend that you either:

- Start using a different directory to store it, like /tmp - with this approach you will also face the scaling up issue previosly mentioned but for temp files, will suit your needs.
- Use Cloud Storage Buckets to store persistent files that will be available for all your instances to use. This is the ideal solution for a scaling app. You can find more details on how to create this by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-console) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) you can get an example on how to upload files from Cloud Storage into your PHP app.

Hope this helps.