# Uploading Images with Wagtail on Google App Engine causes OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: django, google-app-engine, wagtail, http-status-code-500

I am trying to run a wagtail site on the Google Cloud App Engine standard environment using a cloud instance of mySQL. I followed the documentation provided here: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Almost everything is working except for when users upload images. When a user uploads an image to the deployed site a 500 error is reported to the user, and the error log shows "OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system".

When I run the site locally using the cloud SQL proxy this error does not occur, and I am able to upload images just fine.

Can you advise me on why this would happen, and what to change to avoid this error in deployment?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload the files to the file system (the same directory where you deployed the app). App Engine does not support that because as your app scales to new instances those files would not be replicated, and therefore, if the app is dependent on that it will start to fail, so this behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application.

There are 2 ways you could work around that, as you can see on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759032/12857703) I have provided on a similar issue to the one you are facing:

> - Start using a different directory to store it, like /tmp - with this approach you will also face the scaling up issue previosly mentioned but for temp files, will suit your needs.
> - Use Cloud Storage Buckets to store persistent files that will be available for all your instances to use. This is the ideal solution for a scaling app.

You can find more details on how to create this by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-console) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) you can get an example on how to upload files to Cloud Storage from your Python app.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve this problem using two cloud storage buckets (static and media) and by switching to the google cloud flexible app engine environment. However, I still had problems with accessing images that were uploaded to my google cloud bucket. I used this django-storage tutorial and now it all works: https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05 to solve that problem

Comment: Good to know that you were able to solve the issue @allthingsdeveloper, please do consider upvoting the answer I have provided if you felt it was useful, and also do consider adding a complementary asnwer of your own describing what you did in order to fix it and accept it, that way others in the community will be able to find the solution easily, and this will also help you increase your own reputation on Stack Overflow.